# NuGet command line has been stopped working

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

i cant built a solution, and this errors occurs ,
the error window is given below. how can i solve this error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX0Ce.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error usually happen when one or more file that you used in your nuget in current project is missing or corrupted.

**Try Restoring :** 
Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console command.
Type `Update-Package -Reinstall`

or

`Update-Package -Reinstall -ProjectName myProj`

Answer (score 0):

Usually it happens when you do multiple task simultaneously in the IDE.

At the status bar , it says  `rebuild are started...`

Another problem is with your nuget command-line console ,

you need to enter the command after u see the `PM>` at the console , while your command is `'INSTRUCTION'`

Answer (score 0):

I installed .Net framework 4.5 it is working for me